# MySQL: alias column name question

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to alias a column name with the result of a simple SELECT query.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT `hlevel1` AS (SELECT `level1` FROM `hierarchy_labels` LIMIT 1) FROM `hierarchy`;
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

Aliases are used to rename a field or to name a calculated field.

If you simply want your results to be named 'hlevel1', you may want to try this:

```
SELECT level1 as hlevel1 FROM hierarchy_labels LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement.

```
SELECT `level1` INTO @x FROM `hierarchy_labels` LIMIT 1;
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT `hlevel1` AS `', @x, '` FROM `hierarchy`');
PREPARE s FROM @s;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```